# Passing Error Data from Firebase OR Server respose to Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, formik

I have a form that I have created using Formik and that I have synced up to firebase.  I have split the code between a few files, two of which are the following:

```
// form.js
import React from 'react'

import { Button } from 'UI'
import { Form, Email, TextInput as Text, Password } from 'UI'

export const FormFields = ({ errors, isSubmitting, isValid }) => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>
      <Text name="name" />
      <Email name="email" />
      <Password name="password" />
      <Password name="confirmPassword" />
      <Button disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

// index.js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'

import { firebase } from 'Classes'

import { FormFields as Form } from './form'
import { validationSchema } from './validation'
import { initialValues } from './values'

export const SignUpForm = () => {
  const [authError, setAuthError] = useState(null)
  console.log('authError: ', authError)

  async function authenticateUser(values) {
    const { name, email, password } = values
    try {
      await firebase.register(name, email, password)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Authentication error: ', error)
      setAuthError(error.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <Formik
        render={props => {
          console.log('props: ', props)
          return <Form {...props} />
        }}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={async (
          values,
          { authError, setError, setErrors, setSubmitting, resetForm }
        ) => {
          setSubmitting(true)
          authenticateUser(values)
          setSubmitting(false)
          resetForm()
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

I have tested it out and (almost) everything works just fine.

My question has to do with displaying error messages from Firebase.  I am receiving any error messages on the `authenticateUser` function which is located in the `index.js` file.  Those errors are being stored in the `authError` variable that I set with `useState`.  It works as it is supposed to.

What I would like to do is to pass that variable or those error values over to the `form.js` file so that I can display them in the form fields if need be.

And that is what I am having a difficult time figuring out how to do.  Do I need to create a context to pass the values over?  Is there an easier and/or more direct way of sharing those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to rely on errors from server you would have to set it inside `Formik`'s `onSubmit` using `setErrors` or `setFieldError` method and set your specific fieldname's error message.

Something like below may achieve that result:

```
export const SignUpForm = () => {
  // const [authError, setAuthError] = useState(null)
  // console.log('authError: ', authError)

  async function authenticateUser(values, setFieldError) {
    const { name, email, password } = values
    try {
      await firebase.register(name, email, password)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Authentication error: ', error)
      // setAuthError(error.message)
      setFieldError("myErrorFieldName", error.message) // <-------------------
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <Formik
        render={props => {
          console.log('props: ', props)
          return <Form {...props} />
        }}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={async (
          values,
          { authError, setError, setErrors, setSubmitting, resetForm, setFieldError }
        ) => {
          setSubmitting(true)
          authenticateUser(values, setFieldError) // <-------------------
          setSubmitting(false)
          resetForm()
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

And in your form.js you would have to code based on errors object field existence value:

```
export const FormFields = ({ errors, isSubmitting, isValid }) => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>
      <Text name="name" />
      <Email name="email" />
      <Password name="password" />
      <Password name="confirmPassword" />
      <Button disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
      { errors.myErrorFieldName &&  <p>errors.myErrorFieldName</p> } // <----------
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Alternatively you can use `<ErrorMessage name="myErrorFieldName"/>` component to show the message: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage#docsNav

Comment: -- Thanks.  That did it.  The only exception was the `ErrorMessage` component.  That did not work for me (i.e., nothing showed up).  But everything else worked and solved my problems.  Again, thanks.

Comment: Glad that it worked out. `ErrorMessage` component is from formik and you would have to use exact field name on which you are setting error on, either way whatever works for you should be good enough, both serves the same purpose.